# How to customize name of serialized properties with Liberty jaxrs-2.0 feature?

Tags: json, annotations, jackson, jaxb2

I'm struggling with a problem that in the past I easily solved with a couple of annotation, but now there is no way to get the same effect. What I'm trying to do is just change the names of the properties of a bean when it is serialized as application/json using the JAXRS data binding feature. On Liberty Profile with jaxrs-1.0 feature I was able to achieve this result simply adding the Jackson annotation @JsonProperty; now, with the new jaxrs-2.0 feature these properties are completely ignred and the bean is serialized withe the exact name of the POJO attributes. Looking around I read that Liberty 8.5.5.6 use Apache CXF instead of Jackson. How can I achieve the same result also with this library/framework? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: probably you could use `@XmlElement` and other `javax.xml.bind.annotation` annotations. Or switch back to Jackson... By default  Apache CXF uses Jettison, so i think you could also swithc back to Jackson if you want to. http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-data-bindings.html#JAX-RSDataBindings-Jackson

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion! I was focused on JSON serialization and I didn't thought to annotate the POJO with JAXB annotations! adding @XmlElement annotation did the job! I'm still trying to figure out how to configure Jackson JSON provider in Liberty, maybe it is just a matter of adding jackson-jaxrs-json-provider dependency to my app and rely on SPI auto-registration...